# Android Nativescript App Prompting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Tags: android, google-play, nativescript, android-bluetooth, google-play-console

I'm trying to release an NS8 app on the Google Play Store. The app needs bluetooth to work, since it connects to other devices. I'm going to target SDK 30 due to Google Play policy.

I know that in order to get that to work, I need to declare the following permissions in the AndroidManifest

`ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`

However, when I upload a Bundle to the Google Play, I get the following warning

`This release includes permissions that haven't been declared in Play Console. Go to Sensitive app permissions to update your permission declarations.`

I guess I need to make a prompt in the app to ask for background location permission. Using `nativescript-community/ble` I know request FINE_LOCATION already. But I'm wondering, how do I get an explicit prompt for background location access? I need one for my video.

EDIT: So I managed to find some code that manually prompts for location, so I'm trying to adapt it for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`, but I still need help.

```
import {
   AndroidActivityRequestPermissionsEventData,
   AndroidActivityResultEventData,
   AndroidApplication,
   android as andApp
} from '@nativescript/core/application';

...

let permissionCb = (args: AndroidActivityRequestPermissionsEventData) => {
                        console.log(args);
                        console.log(args.requestCode);
                        console.log(args.permissions);
}
              

andApp.on(AndroidApplication.activityRequestPermissionsEvent, permissionCb);

const neededPermission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
                    

androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this._getActivity(), [neededPermission], 0);
```

The problem is, my app isn't recognizing `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`. What should I do?

Comment: What do you need background permission for? Isn't foreground permission enough?

Comment: @Emil according to Android Developer docs -> “ Services running on Android 10 and higher cannot discover Bluetooth devices unless they have the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. For more information on this requirement, see Access location in the background.”

Comment: Thus I think I’m forced to have that permission.

Comment: If you just need to scan Bluetooth devices while the screen shows your app, then you don't need the background permission.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I might not need the background permission if my app is in the foreground? ( My app scans for bluetooth devices while in foreground and at specific times which is initiated by the user)

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! I only needed the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that only the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION was necessary since my app's bluetooth capability only scans in the foreground anyway.